# Delete the bracket block with first word just before the start of bracket

Tags: vim

I have a file which has the following structure:

```
start {
abc
xyz
some thing
other thing
}
start {
hi
bye
}
someOtherStart {
yes
no
ok
}
start {
heello
}
```

How can I delete all the `start` blocks meaning delete start as well as the `{ }` block.
The final result should be like:

```
someOtherStart {
yes
no
ok
}
```

EDIT:
`start` block can have nested `{`.
What did I had tried:
I search for `/start {` and then I tried recording the below command:

```
n    // go to next match
f {  // put cursor on {
d%   // delete the block
dd   // delete the start line as well
```

and then I tried replaying it. But I thought there might be some better way to do it as my file has more than 1 million lines.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Updated in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most idiomatic way to do what you want is to use the `:help :global` command:

```
:g/^start/,/^}/d
```

or, if the notion of "block" is important (possibility of nested blocks):

```
:g/^start/norm vaBVd
```

Let's break the first one down:

- `g/<pattern>/<command>` executes `<command>` on each line matching `<pattern>`,
- `^start` is the `<pattern>`, it matches the string `start` at the beginning of the line,
- `,/^}/d` is the `<command>`, shortened for `.,/^}/d`, means "delete every line from the current line to the next line that starts with `}`". See `:help :d` and `:help :range`.

The `<command>` in the second one is a little bit different:

- `:norm <macro>`, short for `:normal <macro>`, executes `<macro>` as if you were in normal mode,
- `vaBVd` is the `<macro>`, it:

  - visually selects the closest pair of braces with `vaB`, see `:help v`, `:help aB`, and more generally `:help motion`,
  - forces the visual selection to become linewise and thus include the `start` ,
  - and then deletes the visually selected lines with `:help d`.

---

The `:global` command is briefly introduced in chapter 10 of the user manual, `:help usr_10`, and then used creatively in several other places.

Answer (score 2):

To do it interactively, I would

- put the cursor at the first `start` (e.g. <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>)
- do <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>%</kbd> to delete it down to the closing `}` including the newline after it,
- repeat via <kbd>.</kbd> as many times as it's needed.

A bit less interactive approach is this: <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>`someOtherStart`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but this only works if the text before `someOtherStart` consists of `start { }` blocks as your example implies.

---

If you think there might be something between the `start {}` blocks that need not be deleted, then you might need some non-interactive approach.

If that's the case, please, update the example in the question so that it doesn't lack any fundamental feature.

A solution such as [Friedrich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77271235/5825294)'s or such as the following

```
:1s/^\%(start {\_.\{-}}\n\)\+//
```

will end up breaking down as soon as you apply them to a generalized case, e.g. a case where the various `start`s are actually different strings; or when the various `start {}` can be nested.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "breaking down"? Your `:s` command and mine differ in that yours starts from the top while mine tries to match every line, even when non-`start` blocks are interleaved. While the pattern is similar, the behavior is fundamentally different. Your handling of newline is clever, I somehow missed the obvious.

Comment: @Friedrich, I've given some hints about how the question lacks some crucial information. My comment was not meant to be negative to your answer.

Comment: Don't worry, I did not take it to be negative. Everybody wins if the pros and cons of different solutions are discussed and weighed against each other. Thank you for clarifying your answer.

Answer (score 2):

To do it non-interactively, you can use the following two commands:

```vim
:%s/\<start\>\_.\{-}}
:%g/^$/d
```

The first line finds the whole word "start" `\<start\>`, followed by any character including line breaks [`\_.`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C_.), repeated as few times as possible [`\{-}`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%7B) until a closing curly brace is found `}` and replaces it with nothing. This will remove the `start { ... }` blocks but leave the trailing newline. This is already close to the solution.

The second command removes all empty lines throughout the buffer, cleaning up behind the `:substitute` command. This is somewhat optional so I did not bother to chain it to the first command.

For reference, see [`:help :s`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3As), [`:help pattern`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html) and [`:help :g`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Aglobal).